# How could I add an mp3 player "wordpress plugin" to a site made from scratch?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, mp3

I want to add the [wp-flash-player-widget](http://sexywp.com/flash-player-widget.htm) to a site I'm making from scratch(outside of word press or any CMS system).  Is this possible?  How would I do that?  Thank you.

Comment: Download the plugin, look through the code and see if you can figure out what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

download the ziped file, copy the flash file (the mp3player.swf), and copy the html from the flash-player-widget.php

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mp3player.swf?playlist=playlist.xml" width="100" height="300" wmode="transparent">
<param name="movie" value="mp3player.swf?playlist=playlist.xml" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

Comment: So, I just add those to the root of my FTP directory?  Will it automatically reference them?  Where do add the actual mp3 file to that code above?  Thank you for responding!

Comment: i guess so, unless the files are in the same folder, you may need to add a path before the filenames in the html above, for the mp3s: check out the playlist.xml, also included in the zip file